# Different script results from identical shortcut and console input

Tags: powershell

I am trying to input 2 args from a shortcut and automatically assign them like this:

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile -File d:\scripts\swap-parms.ps1 A 7
```

This script works perfectly when run from the console, but not from a shortcut!

```
[int]$digit = 6                          #Default values.
[String]$variable = 'X'
Write-Host $args[0].GetType().Name  #Shows both as String from hortcut!
Write-Host $args[1].GetType().Name
switch($args) { #Allows any order of input parameters and assigns.
    {$_.GetType().Name -eq 'Int32'}  {$digit = $_ ; continue}
    {$_.GetType().Name -eq 'String'} {$variable = $_}
}
$digit
$variable
```

I know I can do this with named parameters like '-var B -dig 2' but, as it works perfectly from the console I can't understand why it fails with identical args from the shortcut. Ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-command` instead of `-file`. For proof:

```
==> powershell -noprofile -file D:\PShell\SO\swap-parms.ps1  A 33
String
String
6
33

==> powershell -noprofile -command D:\PShell\SO\swap-parms.ps1  A 33
String
Int32
33
A

==>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, sir. It works as you say.